# Android - Cannot Be Resolved to a Variable

Tags: java, android, scope

I'm attempting to code my first Android App for a friend, and the basic function is to display a random quote from one of three characters when a button is clicked. (Sorry for the poor terminology.)

The issue I'm having is in returning a quote chosen at random out of an array after having accessed that array with another randomly generated number and if/else if terms.

I have one package that I'm hoping to access from the Main Activity using

`String quote = mDoctorWho.getDoctorQuote;`

That package has my if/else if statements in it here:

```
private Nine mNine = new Nine();
private Ten mTen = new Ten();
private Eleven mEleven = new Eleven();

public String getDoctorQuote() {

    // Choose a Random number out of three values
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);

    // Use that value to choose which of the Doctors to get a quote from
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        // Quote from Nine
        String quote = mNine.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        // Quote from Ten
        String quote = mTen.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        // Quote from Eleven
        String quote = mEleven.getQuote();
    }
    else {
        String quote = "Error";
    }
    return quote;
}
```

The last line above, to return quote, is the one getting the error 'quote cannot be resolved into a variable'.

mNine, mTen, and mEleven are all nearly-identical packages that look about like this:

```
public String[] mElevenQuotes = {
        "Quote here",
        "Quote here",
        "Quote here" };

public String getQuote() {

    String quote = "";

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(mElevenQuotes.length);

    quote = mElevenQuotes[randomNumber];

    return quote;
}
```

(I removed the quotes so that they wouldn't take up room - I wasn't sure whether this package of code would be useful or not.)

I've looked for a solution and have tried figuring out a problem with the scope, but haven't found a fix. How can I return the quote to the main activity after having it choose a random character, and then a random quote from that character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are declaring the `quote` variaable within if blocks. so outside the blocks there is no existence. Do something like this

```
public String getDoctorQuote() {

    String quote = "";  //  declare the variable before 
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);

    // Use that value to choose which of the Doctors to get a quote from
    if (randomNumber == 0) {
        // Quote from Nine
        quote = mNine.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        // Quote from Ten
        quote = mTen.getQuote();
    }
    else if (randomNumber == 2) {
        // Quote from Eleven
        quote = mEleven.getQuote();
    }
    else {
        quote = "Error";
    }
    return quote;
}
```